# Apache proxy removes double slash

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy

I'm trying to send requests to a docker image by using apache's proxy functionality. The request to the docker should look something like: `https://127.0.0.1:8282/somepath/https://somedomain/someimage.jpg` but it is being forwarded like `https://127.0.0.1:8282/somepath/https:/somedomain/someimage.jpg` (so missing one slash).

I think this is probably some default to prevent issues with directories accidentaly having double slashes, but can I somehow change some setting that makes it not do this? Or can I put it back using some rewrite regex magic?

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the protocol in your receiving app, no need to have https:// in the url right?

Perhaps use nginx as substitue for the proxy?

Comment: the receiving app is a docker image which I just get as-is, so it's hard to handle there. Other alternative is indeed nginx, but I use Apache as server+proxy, so that means migration or adding nginx to the mix (both not nice). One other solution I may have is to let my Spring Boot api handle this, as that is also behind this proxy.

Comment: You could use another pubic port for this